# Oracle DB Access

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, database-replication

I have a client/server application currently that has a Oracle 10G database. The company that I purchased the application form is not providing support. The company when I purchased the application provided me a SQL tool with a READ Only access access to approx 30-40 views.

Based on my analysis the views provide some but not all the data and I want access to data which may be in other tables

I am not a developer but the business owner so excuse my naivety in some of the questions below.

1. Can I export/duplicate/replicate the Oracle DB to another Oracle DB and will a Oracle DBA be able to view/access all the tables and understand the relationships
2. What is the best way to create a duplicate DB that keeps in sync with the application DB which we currently have. We would like to use the Duplicate DB as a backend for a website.

Thanks a lot!

ML

Comment: Just to be clear, is the Oracle database actually installed on a server that you own?  Or is the database installed on a third party server that you merely have access to?

Comment: Justin, Yes I own the application and the server where it resides.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Oracle database resides on a server in your organization, it seems premature to be talking about talking about replicating the data to a different database.  It is certainly possible to do so.  But you can also run many, many different applications against the same database.  Unless you know that the current database server would not be able to cope with the additional workload of the new application or you are planning on investing the time and effort to transform the data into better data model as part of replicating the data (which  is extremely unlikely if you don't already know what the underlying data model is and if you don't already know that this data model isn't going to work well for the new application), you probably want to start with the assumption that you can probably build the new application against the existing database.

A database developer or a DBA should be able (again, assuming that you own the server) to determine what underlying tables exist.  That person should be able to at least get some idea of how the tables relate to each other based on the existing view definitions.  If the original company did a good job building the database, a new developer/ DBA should have a relatively easy time understanding the relationships.  If the original company did shoddy work or was intentionally secretive, it will be a more challenging undertaking.

Comment: Justin - Thank you very much. Yes the application is installed on a server that we own and control. The reason for replicating are several namely: 1. The existing application is designed for a specific workflow process and is integral to our day to day work I dont want the new app (website) hitting against the production DB. 2. The website uses the same data elements but the data model is different. QUESTION - How do I get a copy of the Oracle DB made so that I can have a DBA evaluate it without giving them access to the production DB or server? Is that possible?